# Advanced custom fields - relationships logic reversed

Tags: wordpress, relationships, advanced-custom-fields

On our site we currently have 'work' posts that we create and then associate with an author and genre post type.

The overall goal is:
When we view an author or genre post we want to list all the work posts that we have associated/related with that certain author/genre.

We are using the following code which seems to have us half way...

```
    <?php $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                        'key' => 'related_posts',
                        'value' => $post->id
                )
        )
    );
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
    var_dump($posts_array);
    if( $posts_array ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $posts_array as $related ) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="' . $related->guid . '">' . $related->post_title . '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    ?>
```

However the 'value' field in the array doesn't work. It technically should be passing the id of the current post (author or genre) and selecting the related content. When we remove this from the array it does bring all the posts in whether they are related or not.

In summary, we think that the 'value' problem may be the key in resolving the issue as that is what should be filtering the posts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

did you try `$post->ID`? (uppercase not lowercase)

Comment: what I would do is investigate further by adding, between the `<li>` tags, `the_field( 'related_posts' );`. What happens when you do that?

Comment: The same problem its bring all posts.

Comment: what I meant was, what does `the_field( 'related_posts' )` output? You can check if it's blank by outputting it like this instead: `echo "The related post is:" . get_field( 'related_posts' );`. In other words, are you sure that the posts on which you've set the custom field 'related_posts` are actually spitting out the expected value? Another way to check this is in the `Edit Post` screen in the Dashboard, turn on the toggle which displays Custom Fields (in the top right there's a drop-down menu called "Screen Options"). This will show you which Custom Fields are associated with this post.

Comment: Nothing is being returned. If we remove the 'value' parameter in the array named 'meta_query' then all posts are returned, whether they are related or not. This seems to be the problem but we can't rectify it. Ideally we want to pass the id of the current post and only return the related posts. The examples we have seen of this use our method but ours doesn't work.

Comment: How about in the Dashboard, are any values set there?